# JPA: Entity X has a OneToMany relationship to itself. How?

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, one-to-many

I have one Entity call `Comment`

`Comment`
+ id (PK)
+ fromUserId
+ targetId
+ replyId : This is the foreign key to **id**

The idea is a `comment` can have many replies, but a `reply` is also a `comment`. To distinguish between the two, a `comment` will have `replyId` equal -1, meanwhile a `reply` will have a non -1 value for `replyId`. Ultimately, what I want is for `Comment` to have a `List` like this

```
List<Comment> replyList;  //So each comment will store all their replies into this List
```

In JPA, I accomplish `OneToMany` relationship between two Entity, I create a List with the help of `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` annotation, but in this case I am not sure how to accomplish this. Please help

**EDIT**
They way I create a Comment - Reply layout is by having one dataTable inside another

```
<h:form id="table">
<p:dataTable value="#{bean.comments}" var="item">
    <!-- Original Comment -->
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{item.comment}" />
    </p:column>

    <!-- Reply -->
    <p:column>
        <p:dataTable value="#{item.replies}" rendered="#{item.replies.size() > 0}" var="item2">
             <!-- Print out replies in here -->
             <h:outputText value="#{item2.comment}" />
        </p:dataTable>

        <!-- Text box and commandButton so user can add new reply -->
        <h:inputTextarea value="#{...}" />
        <p:commandButton value="Post" actionListener="#{bean.addReply(item)}" />
        <!-- Assume that I got this working, that a new Comment with correct REPLYTO_ID set -->
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Here is my problem. When I type a reply and click `Post`, it creates an item entry in my database correctly, and after that recall `getReplies()`. I was assume at this point, `replies.size() == 1`, however `replies.size()` is equals to 0. Therefore I see nothing. I have to refresh the page, to see it display correct. I kind of see the problem here, since I generated the value of the second table by `#{item.replies}`, therefore if `item` is not update to date, then `replies` is not update to date. Not sure if this is JSF or JPA problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can map a self referencing entity like this:

```
@Entity
public class Comment {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional=true, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="REPLYTO_ID")
    private Comment replyTo;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="replyTo")
    private List<Comment> replies = new ArrayList<Comment>();

    //...

    // link management method
    public void addToComments(Comment comment) {
        this.comments.add(comment);
        comment.setParent(parent);
    }
}
```

Where the root `Comment` has no `replyTo`.

PS: make sure to set the bi-directional association correctly.

Comment: In the JPQL, if u want to look for only the root `Comment`, you say something like this: `SELECT c from COMMENT c WHERE c.replyTo IS NULL`. Is that right?

Comment: @Harry Yes, that's what I meant by "no replyTo", the root comment doesn't have any replyTo so it's null.

Comment: Thank you, I got that part working. However I kind of ran into another issue related to the one you just answer. I wrote some code, would u please take a look at my post, the EDIT part. I can post this as a separate question if u want me to, but I just dont know what to put for the title.

Comment: @Harry Just to be sure, do you set both sides of the association correctly?

Comment: yeah. I actually figure out what wrong. Just like I said, `since I generated the value of the second table by #{item.replies}, therefore if item is not update to date, then replies is not update to date.` So in the method that I post a reply, I update the list of the original comments. That fixes it. Thank you for all your help. :D

Comment: Hi, Pascal. I know I have posted this question a while back, but I have another question related to this again. Would you be kindly enough to take a look at this link, please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569857/jsf-how-to-update-the-list-after-delete-an-item-of-that-list

Comment: is that to set the `optional` to `false`?? I want to be sure all my entities have the relation