# How to update the list after delete an item of that list

Tags: java, jpa

It will take a moment for me to explain this, so please stay with me. I have table `NewsFeed` that has OneToMany relationship with itself.

```
@Entity
public class NewsFeed(){
    ...
    @ManyToOne(optional=true, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="REPLYTO_ID")
    private NewsFeed replyTo;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="replyTo", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<NewsFeed> replies = new ArrayList<NewsFeed>();

    public void addReply(NewsFeed reply){        
       replies.add(reply);
       reply.setReplyTo(this);
    }

    public void removeReply(NewsFeed reply){
       replies.remove(reply);
    }
}
```

So you can think like this. Each feed can have a `List` of replies which are also type `NewsFeed`. Now it is very easy for me to delete the original feed and get the updated list back. All I need to do after delete is this.

```
feeds = scholarEJB.findAllFeed();  //This will query the db and return updated list
```

But I am having problem when trying to delete `replies` and getting the updated list back. So here is how I delete the `replies`. Inside my JSF managed bean I have

```
//Before invoke this method, I have the value of originalFeed, and deletedFeed set.
//These original feeds are display inside a p:dataTable X, and the replies are
//displayed inside p:dataTable Y which is inside X. So when I click the delete button
//I know which feed I want to delete, and if it is the replies, I will know
//which one is its original post
public void deleteFeed(){
    if(this.deletedFeed != null){
        scholarEJB.deleteFeeds(this.deletedFeed); 
        if(this.originalFeed != null){
            //Since the originalFeed is not null, this is the `replies`
            //that I want to delete
            scholarEJB.removeReply(this.originalFeed, this.deletedFeed);
        }
        feeds = scholarEJB.findAllFeed();
    }        
}
```

Then inside my EJB scholarEJB, I have

```
public void removeReply(NewsFeed feed, NewsFeed reply){
    feed = em.merge(feed);
    comment.removeReply(reply);
    em.persist(comment);
}

public void deleteFeeds(NewsFeed e){
    e = em.find(NewsFeed.class, e.getId());
    em.remove(e);
    em.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evict(NewsFeed.class); //Like fdreger suggested
}
```

When I get out, the entity (the reply) get correctly removed from the database, but inside the `feeds` List, reference of that `reply` still there. It only until I log out and log back in that the reply disappear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have written is correct, requerying should work (and in factis how it's usually done), so the problem must be somewhere else. For example if you delete the entity by any means other than the remove method, it may still be in the 2nd level cache. Or maybe the requerying does not happen at all because of some small mistake?

---

**Update**: After reading the new version of the original question (with all the new sources and clarification about Eclipselink) I made a little test, and it is - indeed - a second level cache problem. A bit strange, and possibly either a bug or an underspecified corner case. To fix it, evict comments from cache:

```
// this goes after em.remove(e)
em.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evict(Comment.class);
```

You could also try evicting the parent of the removed entity only (there is an overloaded version of evict).

Uhmpf. Maybe someone with more street cred (BalusC? :-) should change tags on this post. Turned out it has nothinh to do with JSF.

Comment: Thank you. I delete the entity by `remove` method. If I delete the original post, then it work great. Entity got remove, the list got re-update. Not sure why it does not work with the replies. Can you talk more about 2nd level cache?

Comment: It's either a major bug in your JPA implementation (judging from the usage of lazy it might be eclipselink - is it?), or a major bug in Primefaces, or a small overlooking in your application. Try and debug (a couple of out.printlns in a for loop will do) the value returned from myEJB.getAllComments. This way you will know: 1) if the method gets called at all, 2) if the returned data looks fine (my shoot is that it's not called at all)

Comment: Yup it is eclipselink, I will do as you said. Back in a bit

Comment: Well I check with debugger, the method that re-query did get called. Plus, if I delete the original post, then it work fine. This driving me nut. Gosh, it is new year, and I stuck with this problem. Seems so trivial, why the hell does it not work :(

Comment: I updated my post a bit, please take a look and see if it shed u any light. Thank you and happy new year

Comment: At this point I don't really understand the problem. I take it that Comment/NewsFeed are the same class, only from different copy/pastings? I do not see how any reply could be removed at all, using the above code (maybe something is missing?). A couple of comments earlier you said that replies were removed with EntityManager#remove; looking at the code I see that no such thing happens, you simply remove them from the replies list, which theoretically cannot work, as there is no orphanRemoval=true in the @OneToMany.

Comment: `NewsFeed` is in fact `Comment`. Sorry about the confusion. I fix it so that the code make more sense now. I tried to evict the cache like u suggest above, but unfortunately, it does not work for me. Did evict the cache work for your example, fdreger?

Comment: I figure it out. Your evict cache work. The problem is my `removeReply()`. What I try to do was, at first I realize that after I delete the replies, there still a cache , so I add `removeReply()`, which the hope of completely removing the replies from the original feed. However, the `persist` action in that method, somehow put the deleted Entity back into database. Now after removing that method, and add your suggestion. It works great. Thank you. I wish I can give u more vote. U deserve it. Thanks again

Comment: A note of warning about evicting a single entity in JPA: ``em.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evict(Comment.class);``. This is a rather unsafe operation, as it might leave the cache in an inconsistent state. There could now be dangling references to uncached objects. If you need to do eviction use evictAll, which is safe.

Comment: Thank you. But I am assume that evictAll() will suffer a bit of performance degradation, since it clear out all the cache, is that right?

Answer (score 3):

When you delete an object you must remove all reference to that object before deleting it.  If you do not, you can get a constraint error, or stale data in your persistence context, or in the 2nd level cache.

When removing the Feed, first remove it from the replies.

Comment: that might be my problem as well. If you take a look at my code. I actually remove the feed first, then remove it from the replies. Are you saying that if I flip the order around, it will work. As it right now, I use what fdreger suggest, and evict second level cache. It works right now. But it also good to know if there are any other way to do it